# PowerQuery: How can I transform a table by dividing the columns by columnspecific factors?

Tags: function, powerquery, each

I have a table ("Index") which I want to transform by dividing all columns except "Date" by columnspecific factors. The factors are stored in a table named "normfactor" which has the same columnheaders as "Index" and only one row.

Table "Index":

| Date | Zone 1 | Zone 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1.8 | 1.4 |
| 02 | 1.9 | 1.5 |

Table "normfactor":

| Zone 1 | Zone 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0.98 | 0.97 |

I found a function I could use to divide the columns of "Index" by a fixed factor (here the normfactor of the first column):

```
let
        Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Index"]}[Content],
        ZoneColumnNames = List.RemoveMatchingItems(Table.ColumnNames(Quelle), {"Date"}),
        fn_devide_column_by_factor = (fnRec as record) as list => List.Transform(ZoneColumnNames, each {_, each _ / Table.Column(normfactor, ZoneColumnNames{0}){0}}),
        #"transform" = Table.FromRecords(Table.TransformRows(Source, (Rec) => Record.TransformFields(Rec, fn_devide_column_by_factor(Rec))))
    in
        #"transform"
```

How can I write this variable, so it doesn't always divide by the normfactor of the first column, but by the normfactor in the column with the same columnname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way

```
// code for index table using normfactor table
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Columns = List.RemoveItems(Table.ColumnNames(Source),{"Date"}),
Transforms = List.Transform(Columns,(x)=>{x, each _ /  Table.Column(normfactor,x){0}  , type number}),
Transformit = Table.TransformColumns(Source, Transforms)
in Transformit
```

another way

```
// code for index table using normfactor table
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index", "Date"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "NewValue", each [Value] / Table.Column(normfactor,[Attribute]){0}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Value"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "NewValue", List.Sum),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in  #"Removed Columns1"
```

Comment: I prefer your first method

Comment: I have not tested speed for the pivot/unpivot vs ()=> Do you happen to know relative performance?

Comment: I have not, but I would think a transform would be faster than all of the operations needed in your second method.